# Event Listener for App Maker Text Editor Widget

Tags: google-app-maker

I would like to add an event listener to a Text Editor but I cannot seem to get it to work.

In the past I have been able to add event listeners to Text Box and Text Area widgets by adding some script to the onAttach event of the widget:

```
widget.getElement().addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
   // event listener code goes here...
});
```

However, this approach does not seem to work with the Text Editor widget and the only events that I am able to use are the onValueChange or onValueEdit App Maker events, which only trigger when the Text Editor loses focus

Is there any way that I get such an event listener to work with a Text Editor widget?

Can anyone suggest how I can overcome this problem?

Comment: Our of curiosity, why do you need it? By the way, did you try `onInputChange` event for TextBox and TextArea widgets?

Answer (score 0):

I extremely discourage you to use this approach, since App Maker can change TextEditor's implementation/DOM structure anytime, unless you have no other options...

```js
// text editor's onAttach event
widget.getElement().children[1].children[1].children[0].contentDocument.children[0].children[1].addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
   console.log(e);
});
```

It also would be a good idea [to file feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192783&template=833410), to encourage App Maker to provide this functionality out of the box.